# Set overflow to bottom auto function into jQuery Script

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add this function :

```
$("#overflow").animate({"scrollTop": $('#overflow')[0].scrollHeight}, "slow");
```

into my jQuery script :

```
$('.comment_button').live("click",function() 
{
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var uid = $("#uid").val();
    var comment= $("#ctextarea"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&msg_id=' + ID + '&uid=' + uid;

    if(comment=='')
    {
        $('#ctextarea').html("").fadeIn('slow');
        $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
    }
    else if (!$.trim($("#ctextarea"+ID).val()))
    {
        $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment_ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
                $("#ctextarea"+ID).val('');
                $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

CSS :

```
#overflow
{
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
min-height: 50px;
max-height: 246px;
}
```

and the HTML :

```
<div class="overflow" id="overflow">
bla bla bla
<div>
```

My question is, how to put that function into my jQuery script ?
The logic of the function is, if any new data then it will auto scroll to bottom.

Thanks.

Comment: It goes underneath the line `$("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();` (when your new data successfully arrives).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your code correctly... with this you are going to scroll to the bottom every time there is data on the comment.

```
$('.comment_button').live("click",function() 
{
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var uid = $("#uid").val();
    var comment= $("#ctextarea"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&msg_id=' + ID + '&uid=' + uid;

    if(comment=='')
    {
        $('#ctextarea').html("").fadeIn('slow');
        $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
    }
    else if (!$.trim($("#ctextarea"+ID).val()))
    {
        $("#overflow").animate({"scrollTop": $('#overflow')[0].scrollHeight}, "slow");
        $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment_ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
                $("#ctextarea"+ID).val('');
                $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried. But still cant. Scroll not automatic scroll down